# how do I convert an object to an array list in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with my code it has a running error I am trying to convert an object to an array list. In my code, I was trying to build an array inside an array! I was expecting to have a return value as the following:

```
[['name', 'Holly'], ['age' , 35], ['role', 'producer' ],

['species', 'canine'], ['name', 'Bowser'], ['weight', 45]]
```

I will appreciate any help or advice thanks.

```js
var obj1 = {
  name: 'Holly',
  age: 35,
  role: 'producer'
};
var obj2 = {
  species: 'canine',
  name: 'Bowser',
  weight: '45'
};

function convertObjectToList(obj) {
  var arrayExt = []; // declare my external array container
  var arrayInt = []; // declare my internal arrays container
  var objKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj); // returns all properties (enumerable or not) found directly upon a given object. 
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (var i = 0; i < objKeys.length; i++);
    arrayInt = [];
    arrayInt.push(obj(objKeys[k]));
    arrayExt.push(arrayInt);
    console.log(arrayExt);
  }
}
convertObjectToList(obj);
```

Comment: It sounds like you want [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). It has low browser support, but there are polyfills.

Comment: What is `if (var i = 0; i < objKeys.length; i++);` supposed to be? You're mixing up `if` and `for` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a use a combination of `Object.keys`, `Array.map`, and `Array.concat`

```js
function toArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(k => [k, obj[k]]);
}

var obj1 = { name: 'Holly', age: 35, role: 'producer' };
var obj2 = { species: 'canine', name: 'Bowser', weight: '45'};

console.log(toArray(obj1).concat(toArray(obj2)))
```

In general, you should avoid `for...in` loops. There are many better alternatives now.

Comment: Thanks@AR7 really helped me

Comment: @Salma let me know if you have any followup questions or if anything wasn't clear

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick?

```js
    var obj1 = { name: 'Holly', age: 35, role: 'producer' };
    var obj2 = { species: 'canine', name: 'Bowser', weight: '45'};

    function convertObj(obj) {
        var result = [];
        for (var key in obj) {
            result.push([key, obj[key]])
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    console.log(convertObj(obj1))
    console.log(convertObj(obj2))
```

Gives (NodeJS):

```
> convertObj(obj1)
[ [ 'name', 'Holly' ],
  [ 'age', 35 ],
  [ 'role', 'producer' ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

With ECMAScript2017 you can use Object.entries  or a traditional "for in" loop

```js
var obj1 = {
  name: 'Holly',
  age: 35,
  role: 'producer'
};
var obj2 = {
  species: 'canine',
  name: 'Bowser',
  weight: '45'
};



var arr1 = Object.entries(obj1)

console.log(arr1);

var arr2 = Object.entries(obj2)

console.log(arr2);



//traditional for in loop

var tr1 = [];
for (let iter in obj1) {
  tr1.push([iter, obj1[iter]])

}

console.log(tr1);

var tr2 = [];
for (let iter in obj2) {
  tr2.push([iter, obj2[iter]])

}
console.log(tr2);
```

Comment: NodeJS: `TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'entries'`

Comment: @Fabien upgrade your version of Node

Comment: Damned, maybe :-D Another approach is to use `Object.keys(a).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) { ...`

Comment: this gives the result but gives an undefined

Comment: @salma what can you explain what you mean by undefined? are you getting this in Node?